# MySQL subquery returning multiple rows

Tags: mysql, subquery

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(revenue_date),"/ ", YEAR(revenue_date)) as month_year, 

    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(delivery_date)) as operating_days
    FROM table2 where weekday(delivery_date) <> 5 and     
    weekday(delivery_date) <> 6 and delivery_date < current_time and     
    year(delivery_date) > 2015 GROUP BY YEAR(delivery_date), MONTH(delivery_date)), 
sum(revenue) as total_revenue,
from table1 
where revenue_date < current_time and year(revenue_date) > 2015
group by year(revenue_date), month(revenue_date);
```

This shows the error "subquery returns more than 1 value". If I don't include `group by` in the subquery it returns just a total of all of the months but I need it to return it separately for all months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(MONTH(revenue_date),"/ ", YEAR(revenue_date)) as month_year, a.operating_days
sum(revenue) as total_revenue,
from table2 JOIN
(SELECT YEAR(delivery_date) as `year`, MONTH(delivery_date) as `month`, COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(delivery_date)) as operating_days
    FROM table2 where weekday(delivery_date) <> 5 and     
    weekday(delivery_date) <> 6 and delivery_date < current_time and     
    year(delivery_date) > 2015 GROUP BY YEAR(delivery_date), MONTH(delivery_date)) a
ON year(revenue_date) = a.year AND month(revenue_date) = a.month
where revenue_date < current_time and year(revenue_date) > 2015
group by year(revenue_date), month(revenue_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Join with the subquery.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('%c/%Y', revenue_date) as month_year, 
        sum(revenue) as total_revenue, operating_days
from table1
JOIN (SELECT YEAR(delivery_date) AS delivery_year, MONTH(delivery_date) AS delivery_month, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT DATE(delivery_date)) as operating_days
    FROM table2 
    where weekday(delivery_date) <> 5 and     
        weekday(delivery_date) <> 6 and delivery_date < current_time and     
        year(delivery_date) > 2015 
    GROUP BY delivery_year, delivery_month) AS t2 
ON YEAR(revenue_date) = delivery_year AND MONTH(revenue_date) = delivery_month
where revenue_date < current_time
group by year(revenue_date), month(revenue_date);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I had an error in my question. I am getting data from 2 different tables.

Comment: So change the table names. What's the problem?

Comment: I changed the table names... regardless it doesn't work, it only returns total_revenue, I changed the date format back to `concat` so now it prints date and revenue but not the `operating_days`

Comment: I originally left out `operating_days` in the `SELECT` list, but added that at the same time as I changed the table names.